# How to ignore currently clocked entries?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I would like to iterate all entries from all org-agenda files but those marked as *done* and those currently clocked.

So far, I had success with the first part. However seems like `org-agenda-skip-if` can't detect if an entry is currently clocked.

Right now, what I'm doing to check if the entry is currently clocked is doing a *hackish* string comparison with the value of `org-clock-current-task`

Here is the code I have:

```
 ;; This goes inside a let statement which sets the org-agenda-skip-function
 ;; variable with my function to ignore DONE tasks.
(let* ((entries (org-agenda-get-day-entries file today :scheduled :deadline)))
          (dolist (entry entries)
            (if (and (string-match-p today-regexp (get-text-property 0 'extra entry))
                   (string-empty-p (get-text-property 0 'time entry))
                   (not (string-suffix-p org-clock-current-task (get-text-property 0 'txt entry))))
                (alert "Pending Task for today with unknown time of day"
                       :title (format "%s" (get-text-property 0 'txt entry))
                       :mode 'org-mode))))
```

Comment: IIUC, there can be at most *one* entry that is currently clocked, right?

Comment: yes, only one entry at the same time